# How can I subset a dataframe to rows relative to column values from another inside a function where that column is a parameter?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

## Context

I want to write a function that will check if update files, namely CSVs of dataframes, have been imported correctly into my ERP (NetSuite).  So I would like to compare the import file to a fixed saved search CSV export which includes all columns.

I can do this manually by

1. loading the import file as `import_df` and saved search export as `master_df` in R,
2. then using dplyr to select from `master_df` the columns of `import_df` and
3. filter the rows of `master_df` to those with the ID values from `import_df`, and finally
4. using symdiff() on the result of the above operations with `import_df`.

If the output of symdiff has zero rows, then I know that the records were updated correctly. If not, then the result tells me which rows did not import correctly so that I can begin troubleshooting.

I would like to wrap all of that into a function which takes two dataframes and the name of the ID column as parameters and then performs the above operations.  I am stuck on step 3, the filtering.

I have read through [programming with dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data--and-env-variables), and posts here and have tried every variation I could think of of `enquo`, embracing/double braces, the `.data` pronoun, `!!`, etc., but it remains more complex than I can internalize and use.

Since I can get the other steps to work, I am focusing my reprex on the filtering step

## Reprex

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Mock data
set.seed(42)
original_master_df <- tibble(
  ID = 1:3,
  x = rnorm(3),
  y = runif(3)
)

import_df <- tibble(
  ID = 4:5,
  x = c(.3, .6)
)

updated_master_df <- bind_rows(import_df, original_master_df)


# Function
find_id_rows_from_x_in_y <- function(x, y, id){
  
  # Naive, non-working dplyr attempt
  y %>% 
    filter(id %in% x$id) # Fix this line.
  
  # Optional alternative naive, non-working base R attempt
  # y[id %in% x[id]] # Fix this line.
}

# Test
find_id_rows_from_x_in_y(
  x = import_df,
  y = updated_master_df,
  id = "ID"
)
#> Error in `filter()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `id %in% x$id`.
#> Caused by error in `x$id`:
#> ! $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
#> Backtrace omitted here for brevity.

# Direct way to generate expected output of test
updated_master_df %>% 
  filter(ID %in% import_df$ID)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      ID     x     y
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4   0.3    NA
#> 2     5   0.6    NA

# ^ Expected output of test ^
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## Question

I cannot find examples of filtering with a function parameter column like this anywhere.  How can I get this function to filter one dataframe with a user-specified column from another? I am inclined toward a dplyr/filter solution, but I am open to base R solutions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't work due to scoping issues. `x` is an argument in your function but also a variable in the data frame you are trying to filter. You can use the rlang pronoun `.env` to specify that `x` is to be found in the function environment and not the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

find_id_rows_from_x_in_y <- function(x, y, id) {
  y %>%
    filter(.data[[id]] %in% .env$x[[id]])
}

find_id_rows_from_x_in_y(
  x = import_df,
  y = updated_master_df,
  id = "ID"
)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ID     x     y
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4   0.3    NA
2     5   0.6    NA
```

You could make things simpler by removing the ambiguity between the function arguments and the variables in the data by renaming the arguments:

```
find_id_rows_from_df1_in_df2 <- function(df1, df2, id) {
  df2 %>%
    filter(.data[[id]] %in% df1[[id]])
}

find_id_rows_from_df1_in_df2(
  df1 = import_df,
  df2 = updated_master_df,
  id = "ID"
)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ID     x     y
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4   0.3    NA
2     5   0.6    NA
```

However, you can get the same result in a more straightforward way by using a `semi_join()`:

```
find_id_rows_from_x_in_y_2 <- function(x, y, id) {
  y %>%
    semi_join(x, by = id)
}

find_id_rows_from_x_in_y_2(
  x = import_df,
  y = updated_master_df,
  id = "ID"
)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ID     x     y
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4   0.3    NA
2     5   0.6    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to use function for the same

```r
find_id_rows_from_x_in_y <- function(x, y, id){
  idz <- sym(id)
  vec <- x[[id]]
  # Naive, non-working dplyr attempt
  y %>% 
    filter(!!idz %in% vec) # Fix this line.
  
  # Optional alternative naive, non-working base R attempt
  # y[id %in% x[id]] # Fix this line.
}

find_id_rows_from_x_in_y(
  x = import_df,
  y = updated_master_df,
  id = "ID"
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ID     x     y
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4   0.3    NA
2     5   0.6    NA
```